# setup media server on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: server, vpn, minidlna

I have get a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04. I want to setup a media server on the VPS, as I plan to use the VPS to download videos, and streaming the video through internet.

I wonder what should I do to achieve this goal?

I have tried the following but not successful so far:

1. Setup `airvideo-server` and VPN on the VPS, then connect to the VPN and use `airvideo` client to watch the video, but don't know why, the file just don't streaming, though it can get the correct information of the video.
2. Setup `minidlna` and VPN on the VPS, then connect to the VPN and use airplayer, but failed to find the server/content.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use dlna on a public server. I've tried a lot of tools (darwin server, etc..) and the best and easiest way is using apache (or other) on server side and vlc on client side.

About apache configuration :

- Configure apache with directories containing the media
- Set up user/password access for specific folders
- If you use links do not forget to add `Options FollowSymLinks` for linked directories/files

About vlc/browser players (or others):

- Both are available on PC/Tablet/Smartphone
- You can browse and play your files directly from your browser

About media server, check those comparisons :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers

A lot of people is using Plex which organizes all media very well, in this website you'll find explanations about setting up plex on a VPS : https://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/43167-plex-media-server-on-a-vps/